# why realm database property value do not change?

Tags: swift, realm

[image]

As above pic, the index is increased one with sequence. when I delete one of index (except for 0), like 3, I hope all index will still in the sequence through 0~5, which means 1 & 2 keep unchanged, 4 decrease to 3, 5->4, 6->5. below is my code:

```
let defaultRealm = try! Realm()
let currentRealm = self.defaultRealm.objects(CurrentRealmObject.self)

let remainedItems = currentRealm.filter("index > \(indexPath.row)")

for item in remainedItems {
    var realmIndex = item.index
    print("before \(realmIndex)")

    try! self.defaultRealm.write {
        realmIndex -= 1
        print("update \(realmIndex)")
    }   
}
```

After I deleted index 3, the realm database become following:
[image]

and print in console is:

```
 before 6
 update 5
 before 4
 update 3
 before 5
 update 4
```

see? values are actually updated, but realm database remains the index unchanged, and its sequence become confused(I'd also like to know why --! and how to keep them in the same sequence).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`var realmIndex = item.index` means that `item.index` was copied to `realmIndex`. No matter how many copied values ​​you change, it does not affect the original object. To update the value of Realm, assign it again or directly manipulate the property rather than the copied value.

1. Assign it again

   ```
   try! self.defaultRealm.write {
       realmIndex -= 1
       item.index = realmIndex
   }
   ```
2. directly manipulate the property

   ```
   try! self.defaultRealm.write {
       item.index -= 1
   }
   ```

For the sequence, As same as other databases, Realm does not keep order. If you would like to get results in sequence, you need to explicitly sort using the `sorted()` method. Or, use Realm's `List<T>` instead. `List<T>` keeps the orders.

Comment: thank you! The first problem solved. Do you know how to fix the sequence of object? Like above, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, when I deleted index 3, I want the sequence to be 0,1,2,4,5,6, but not 0,1,2,6,4,5, which I need the index to be referred as pageController's page, the strange change of sequence will make the page confused.

Comment: @steve 
For the sequence, As same as other databases, Realm does not keep order. If you would like to get results in sequence, you need to explicitly sort using the `sorted()` method. Or, use Realm's `List<T>` instead. `List<T>` keeps the orders. I also edited my answer.